# Importing data from excel sheet on webpage rather than from within phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

Has anyone ever been able to upload an excel sheet to phpmyadmin without doing it manually? On a webpage, I have a upload file with a submit button. Is it possible for the submit button to upload all the data inside of the excel sheet to the tables, without any work from within phpMyAdmin? As a developer, I can do manually upload all the excel sheet information inside of phpMyAdmin, but having a regular staff member use phpMyAdmin may be a bit risky.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post">
    <h1>Upload Excel documents here</h1>
    <input type="file" name="ExcelFile" />
    <input type="submit" name="ExcelInput" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['ExcelInput'])) {
     // how to link action to phpmyadmin. Cannot do regular sql query for insert as excel sheet can differ in length and in amount of data

}
?>
```

Comment: Files that are uploaded are represented in the `$_FILES` array and not the `$_POST` array It is all described [nicely in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: Research: If its a real `.xls` or `.xlsx` file then look up the package PHPSpreadsheet if its a `.csv` then you can start by looking up `fgetcsv()` in the PHP Manual

Comment: I am working with a OpenDocument Spreadsheet, or .ods file

Comment: Then you are in luck, I think [`PHPSpreadheet`](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=ods) works with those also

Comment: Thank you! That document really is helpful. I am still reading through it. Is there any documentation on how to tie the .ods file to a mysql query? As in, being able to insert all the data from the spreadsheet into the database? As stated above, I can import the excel spreadsheet into the database from phpmyadmin

Comment: Just pick out the columns you are interested in, and build an INSERT query. There is no point and click solution, you have to write some code

Comment: _"Is there any documentation on how to tie the .ods file to a mysql query"_ - Have you done any research? A simple search for "php excel to mysql" will give you a ton of results with examples/guides/libraries/tools etc.

Comment: _"how to link action to phpmyadmin"_ - Your application/code has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin (which is just a web based tool for managing MySQL/MariaDB databases, written in PHP). You need to write the features yourself (or look for some ready made solutions)